# Plural of "document"

Tags: grammatical-number

I thought the plural of *document* is *document* itself. Which one is valid, *document* or *documents*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The plural is "documents".

There may be contexts where it is treated as a mass noun, and so has no plural; but I can't think of any.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you mean to use document as a noun or a verb.  As a technical writer, I have written many documents.  Not many document.  In my department we conjugate the verb to document as I document, you document, he/she documents, we document, you document, they document